# bootstrap-package sitepackagebuilder less files compiling

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I used the bootstrap_package and built an extension with the sitepackage builder. https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/
Normally the less files are processed when the template constants are edited in the backend(without sitepackage). After installing the sitepackage the backend editing of the constants gets disabled.
I can now work with less files in my own extension to override/extend the standard less/css stuff. But i cant find out how to process the less files to get compiled :(
Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try EXT from TYPO3 extensions like https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/ws_less/ or configurate Grunt or Gulp for less and then include ready for use css file. Example of config for compiling https://ericnish.io/blog/compile-less-files-with-grunt/

Comment: yes i know i can do it that way, but in the bootstrap_package a less processor is already included, so why i should use another one?